# Differences between session beans and entity beans, and stateful session beans and stateless session beans

Tags: java, ejb

I use SSH for a some while, and some friends ask me what is bean, and difference between session bean and entity bean, and difference between stateful session bean and stateless session bean, is those concept only exists in EJB(I also want to ask is EJB some relation with SSH), or they are general concept?
and what are they?

what i mean SSH is Spring Struts and Hibernate, actually i do not know they three has some relationship with EJB?

And i want to know is that bean is concept in the context of EJB? And when we talks about other framework like SSH, we never said bean?

Comment: Errr... when I see `SSH` I think of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell). Would you mind mentioning what exactly *you* are talking about?

Comment: Ah, I see. Please don't use the SSH acronym for this. SSH has a very old and very prevalent meaning in the area of networking - and computing in general - i.e. it refers to the Secure SHell protocol. Using it like this only creates a lot of confusion that eliminates whatever little efficiency you gain by saving a couple of words...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> what is bean

In context of EJB, bean is a class managed by the container.

> between session bean and entity bean

Session beans represent logic while entity beans represented persistent objects. These days entity beans aren't used anymore in favour to JPA entities.

> difference between stateful session bean and stateless session bean

Once you obtain a reference to stateful session bean, you will always use that particular instance. Stateless session beans are pooled and returned to the clients at random.

> those concept only exists in EJB

Yes, although beans are also present in Spring framework with a similar meaning but different design concepts.

> is EJB some relation with SSH

You can deploy EJBs via SSH using SCP. But seriously, seems like you are confusing SSH with...?